# String split more than one space for adding new column (keywords capturing)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to capture keywords which are in 'Description' to know this job is what I am looking for.

I used string split to add one column from a table which is for keywords in job description.

Here's an example

Job (Table name)

```
ID      Code       Name                Description
1       001       Engineer     This job requires ms sql server.
2       002        CS          You will need to use python and C++.
3       003       Teacher      You must have certificated degree for this position.
4       004       Programmer   Master's degree and C++ required.
5       005       Designer     Experience more than 3 years in specific retail industry.
.        .         .                              . 
.        .         .                              .
```

This

```
.
.
.
```

means I have more rows.

list (table name)

```
   key
ms sql server
Python
Certificated degree
C++
Master's degree
specific retail industry
.
.
```

This is what I have tried.

```
SELECT     ID, Code, Name, Description, String_Agg(v.Keywords, ', ') AS Keywords
FROM        Job as j
outer apply (
    select (Trim(value)) t,
        case when exists 
          (select * from list as list where lower(list.key)=lower(Trim(value))) 
        then Trim(value) end Keywords
        
    from String_Split(Description, ' ')
)v
group by J.ID, J.Code, J.Name, J.Description
```

Actual Output

```
  ID    Code   Name                Description                             Keywords
   2    002    CS            You will need to use python and C++.        Python, C++
   4    004    Programmer    Master's degree and C++ required.            C++
   .     .         .                              .                    .
   .     .         .                              .                    .
```

If 'key' in list table has no space, it is captured well. However, it is not captured if keys have one space or more than one.

My designed output would be

```
ID   Code    Name                Description                                   Keywords
1    001    Engineer    This job requires Ms sql server.                       ms sql server
2    002    CS          You will need to use python and C++.                   Python, C++ 
3    003    Teacher     You must have certificated degree for this position.   Certificated degree
4    004    Programmer  Master's degree and C++ required.                      Master's degree, C++
5    005    Designer  Experience more than 3 years in specific retail industry.specific retail industry
.        .         .                              . 
.        .         .                              .
```

Would someone please help me deal with keywords which have more than one space? If there is a better approach than string split by space, I would appreciate it as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `patindex` + `join` to first find out whether a key-word exists, and then use your `string_agg` approach to combine them.

```
declare @MyTable table ([Description] nvarchar(max));
declare @MyList table ([Key] nvarchar(max));

insert into @MyTable ([Description])
values
('This job requires ms sql server.'),
('You will need to use python and C++.'),
('You must have certificated degree for this position.'),
('Master''s degree and C++ required.'),
('Experience more than 3 years in specific retail industry.');

insert into @MyList ([Key])
values
('ms sql server'),
('Python'),
('Certificated degree'),
('C++'),
('Master''s degree'),
('specific retail industry');

select T.[Description], L.[Key]
from @MyTable T
inner join @MyList L on patindex('%'+L.[Key]+'%', T.[Description]) > -0;
```

Returns

| Description | Key |
| --- | --- |
| This job requires ms sql server. | ms sql server |
| You will need to use python and C++. | Python |
| You must have certificated degree for this position. | Certificated degree |
| You will need to use python and C++. | C++ |
| Master's degree and C++ required. | C++ |
| Master's degree and C++ required. | Master's degree |
| Experience more than 3 years in specific retail industry. | specific retail industry |

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks for your help and it goes well. I just have a last question. After your code,  
I have done 
`SELECT     ID, Code, Name, Description, String_Agg(convert(nvarchar(max),keywords), ', ') AS Keywords
FROM        Job as E

group by E.ID, E.Code, E.Date, E.Name, E.Description
order by ID`

It shows me what I want. But, total rows of two output after `string_agg` and the original table is different. It looks like some of rows are deleted. Do you think my `string_agg` is wrong?

Comment: For only provided data, It looks good. But, My original table has more than 100k and there are deleted rows after `String_Agg` function.

https://dbfiddle.uk/bhJiwT8N 
 
The output would be ok, but would you check how I can improve the last code?